# A closed-form expression for the inverse of a block-matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-inverse, block-matrices

Let $\bf A$ be an $n \times n$ non-singular  matrix over $\mathbb{F}$. 
Let $x$ be a non-zero element of $\mathbb{F}$.
Suppose that  ${\bf 1}_{n}$ is a symbol for  the all-one  vector  of length $n$ over $\mathbb{F}$. 
Now consider the following  $(n+1) \times (n+1)$ matrix and assume that $\bf B$ is a invertible matrix over $\mathbb{F}$. 
$$
{\bf B}=
\left(
 \begin{array}{cc}
x &{\bf 1}^T_{n} \\
 {\bf 1}_{n} & {\bf A}
 \end{array}
 \right).
 $$

My question: Is there a closed-form expression for the inverse of $\bf B$, denoted with ${\bf B}^{-1}$?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Say that
$$B^{-1}=:\begin{pmatrix} b & X^T \\ Y & M \end{pmatrix}.$$
Then using *Schur's complement formula* (thanks to Nathaniel), $b=(x-{\bf1}^TA^{-1}{\bf1})^{-1}$ and $M=(A-x^{-1}{\bf11}^T)^{-1}$. From this, you can compute the vectors
$$Y=-x^{-1}M{\bf1},\qquad X^T=-b{\bf1}^TA^{-1}.$$

Comment: Maybe worth mentioning that this type of result comes immediately from using the [Schur complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement).

Comment: @NathanielJohnston. Of course you're right.